# Can my Spring Boot application run HTTPS only on certain @RequestMappings?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, https

I'm working on a Spring application that is for a smart house. I got the micro-controllers that send data to the Spring application, but I can not implement SSL on them on account of not enough space and processing speed.

On the client-side, I want to use HTTPS, because the client runs on Android.

Can I map certain requests to HTTP and others to HTTPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can we not open two ports from the spring boot application one on 443 other on 80. So that, on https it listens to 443 and on http to 80. So in your app you can configure http on a url to use 80 port and https to use 443 port.

We can do this by, changes in application.properties:

```
#Https settings
server.port=443
server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.jks
server.ssl.key-store-password = secret
server.ssl.key-password = secret
#Http setting
server.http.port=80
```

I am giving an example using Undertow server, you can do this on any application server (tomcat, etc):

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Boot {

    @Value("${server.http.port:0}")
    private Integer httpPort;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Boot.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.addBuilderCustomizers(new UndertowBuilderCustomizer() {

            public void customize(Builder builder) {
                // worker options
                builder.setWorkerThreads(500);
                builder.setWorkerOption(Options.TCP_NODELAY, true);

                // io options
                builder.setIoThreads(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2);

                // socket options
                builder.setSocketOption(Options.BACKLOG, 10000);
                builder.setSocketOption(Options.TCP_NODELAY, true);
                builder.setSocketOption(Options.REUSE_ADDRESSES, true);

                // server options
                builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ALWAYS_SET_KEEP_ALIVE, false);
                builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.ALWAYS_SET_DATE, true);
                builder.setServerOption(UndertowOptions.RECORD_REQUEST_START_TIME, false);

                // Done to keep both http and https port open at production
                if (httpPort > 0)
                    builder.addHttpListener(httpPort, "0.0.0.0");
            }

        });
        return factory;
    }

}
```